# Bash script aborting for loop

Tags: shell-script, scripting

I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash -e
set -e
DATA_DIR=/home/admin/backup_avl_historico/data
DB_HOST=myHost
DB_USER=myPass

#extract table list
logger 'Extracting Table List'
psql -h $DB_HOST -U $DB_USER -c "select table_name from information_schema.tables where table_name like 'avl_historico_%';" -t -o $DATA_DIR/tables.list
array=($(wc -l $DATA_DIR/tables.list))
logger ''$array
total_tables=${array[0]}
logger 'Total tables: '$total_tables

#Get max date
max_date=$(psql -h $DB_HOST -U $DB_USER -t -c "select now() - interval '12 months'")
logger 'Max date: '$max_date

array=($max_date)
date=${array[0]}
logger 'Only date: '$date

#Dump each table
while read table_name
do
logger 'looping...'
        if [ ! -z "$table_name" ]; then
                logger 'Processing table '$table_name
                output=${table_name}_pre_${date}.csv
                psql -h $DB_HOST -U $DB_USER -t -F , -c "COPY (select * from reports.$table_name where fecha < '$max_date') TO STDOUT WITH CSV" -o ${DATA_DIR}/$output
                if [ -f ${DATA_DIR}/$output ];then
                        if test -s ${DATA_DIR}/$output
                        then
                                logger 'Deleting records'
                                psql -h $DB_HOST -U $DB_USER -c "delete from reports.$table_name where fecha < '$max_date'"
                                logger 'Gzipping '$output
                                pigz  ${DATA_DIR}/$output
                                logger 'Moving to S3'
                                aws s3 mv ${DATA_DIR}/$output.gz s3://my-bucket/avl_historico/
                                logger 'Vacuuming table'
                                psql -h $DB_HOST -U $DB_USER -c "vacuum full analyze reports.$table_name"
                        else
                                rm ${DATA_DIR}/$output
                        fi
                fi
        fi
done < $DATA_DIR/tables.list
```

The problem I'm having is that when PostgreSQL exits a statement with the following error:

```
ERROR:  canceling statement due to lock timeout
```

The entire script gets aborted and doesn't continue with the next iteration of `do` the loop.

Any ideas on how to avoid that exit condition would be appreciated, so the script could just skip one iteration, but continue with the rest

Comment: The -e option means "if any pipeline ever ends with a non-zero ('error') exit status, terminate the script immediately"

Comment: Thanks @DalvenjiaI see that I have TWO -e flags, on the first 2 lines, which one should I delete? Both of them?

Comment: @GonzaloVasquez Yes, both of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your script to execute all commands disregarding any failure remove both `-e` flags.
On the other hand, if you still want to terminate the script in case of error, but want to catch a specific one (PostgreSQL in your case) leave only one of the `-e` flags, it doesn't matter which one but a personal preference is on the script not on the shebang, and the way to catch the error is to add an `||` (logical OR) to the end of the command exiting with non 0. What this `||` do is if the previous command exit code is not 0 execute the following one:

```
psql -h $DB_HOST -U $DB_USER -c "delete from reports.$table_name where fecha < '$max_date'" || true
```

The above example will silently catch `psql` non 0 exit codes and continue, you can replace the `true` command for anything you like (log the error, wait some time, etc...) just make sure it exits with 0 or you will end in the same situation. The `true` command does absolutely nothing at all, it just exits with 0 code.

Comment: Ok, I get it, now what if I want to actually "catch" the possible error from `psql` invocations to decide which actions to take?